# Kali Live Boot error

Tags: boot, kali-linux, live-usb, macintosh, bootable

I know this question has sort of been asked before a while back but it doesn't seem to have a answer after extensive googling. Now some time has passed since the last time this was asked and hopefully there is now a fix.

This is the error am getting when loading Kali Linux from a USB stick.

```
APIC 0 microcode ca
[  0.333064] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, 9901 OxFFFF9R853EB3C800 Table is already loaded (20191018/tbdata-520)
[  0.333070] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_RP.CPUO.GCAP due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20191018/psparse-529)
[  0.333081] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_RP.CPUO.PDC due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20191018/psparse-529)
[  0.333273] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, SSDT OxFFFF9A863EB29000 Table is already loaded (20191018/tbdata-520)
[  0.333277] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_RP.CPU1.APPT due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20191018/psparse-529)
[  0.333286] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_RP.CPU1.GCAP due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20191018/psparse-529)
[  0.333290] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_RP.CPU1.PDC due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20191018/psparse-529)
[  0.334700] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, SSDT OxFFFF9AE63EB3C800 Table is already loaded (20191018/tbdata-520)
[  0.334705] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_RP.CPU1.APCT due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20191018/psparse-529)
[  0.334713] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_RP.CPU2.GCAP due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20191018/psparse-529)
[  0.334717] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_RP.CPU2._PDC due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20191018/psparse-529)
[  0.516993] ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 34
[  1.766888] Couldn't get size: 0x8000000000000015
[  1.766933] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[  1.766958] Couldn't get size: 0x8000000000000015
```

I work on a Macbook Pro 2019. Anybody any Idea?

Comment: Looks like this has already been answered in another post: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10000/elementary-os-wont-boot-past-live-cd-screen